# How to find 90% confidence interval for boxcox transformation in R (not the original 95%)?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, transformation, confidence-interval

I'm using the boxcox transformation in R to find the optimal lambda. Now I know the plot shows the 95% confidence interval, but I want to know the 90% confidence interval. How can I code this the right way?

What I have so far:

```
box.basset <- boxcox(basset ~ cut_edge + classic + superior + chic + cust_centr + outgoing + no_nonsense + distant, data=cbbe, lambda=seq(-6,6,0.1))
cox.basset <- data.frame(box.basset$x, box.basset$y)
cox.basset2 <- cox.basset[with(cox.basset, order(-cox.basset$box.basset.y)),]
cox.basset2[1,]
```

cox.basset2[1,] shows me the optimal lambda and I can also see the order of lambdas.

```
box.basset.x box.basset.y
64           0.3    -870.3008
63           0.2    -876.1951
65           0.4    -879.2895
62           0.1    -896.3645
66           0.5    -902.3571
61           0.0    -929.1276
```

Since 0.3 is a weird transformation, I want to know whether 0.5 would still be in a 90% or otherwise acceptable confidence interval. However, whenever I use the following code, I only get 0.3 as an output, even if I set it to 20%

```
box.basset$x[box.basset$y > max(box.basset$y) - 1/2 * qchisq(.90,1)]
[1] 0.3
box.basset$x[box.basset$y > max(box.basset$y) - 1/2 * qchisq(.20,1)]
[1] 0.3
```

Thanks everyone!

PS: I was looking at this post, but the range() resulted in the same problem:
[Finding Optimal Lambda for Box-Cox Transform in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617587/finding-optimal-lambda-for-box-cox-transform-in-r/58271297?noredirect=1#comment102909607_58271297)